# Getting error while trying to remove display objects that are no use anymore

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am getting this error:

attemp to index ? a nil value

in the beginning of the update function. What might be the reason?

```
--Create drop
local createDrop=function()
drop = display.newImage("drop.png")
drop.x=math.random(drop.width, W-drop.width); drop.y=-50
drop.type="drop"
drops:insert(drop)
physics.addBody(drop)
print(drops.numChildren)
end

local dropTimer = timer.performWithDelay ( 1000, createDrop, 0)

 --Remove the drops that is out of screen
 local function update()
   for i=1,drops.numChildren do
      if(drops[i].y>H) then
        drops[i]:removeSelf()
        drops[i] = nil
      end
   end
 end

--Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", function() print(drop.y) end) --to check if the drop that is out off screen is removed.
  Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", update)
```

Comment: Is there a `drops[drops.numChildren]` entry in drops? Or is that one past the end of the table? Finding out which line (and what iteration of the loop) is causing the error would help with the debugging here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove an object when it reaches `>H`, use collision for the object.

It's much cheaper than the `enterFrame` and you don't need to insert the object in a table, it's much more faster than `enterFrame` with a for loop in it. More efficient I would say.

```
--[[
This is the sensor that will collide to your "drop" object and it will automatically remove
itself upon collision.

It is positioned in y = H+10
]]
local removeSensorPoint = display.newRect(0,H+10,W,2)
removeSensorPoint.alpha = 0
removeSensorPoint.type = "removeSensor"
physics.addBody(removeSensorPoint,"static",{isSensor = true})

local createDrop = function()
    drop = display.newImage("drop.png")
    drop.x = math.random(drop.width, W-drop.width); drop.y=-50
    drop.type = "drop"

    physics.addBody(drop)
    drop.collision = function(self,event)
        if event.phase == "began" and event.other.type == "removeSensor" then
            event.target:removeSelf()
        end
    end
    drop:addEventListener("collision")
    print(drops.numChildren)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

the error comes from your runtime it tries remove the object that is already been remove and the runtime continues to run. are you trying to remove an object that reach the bound of the screen you can refer to this code if this is what you want to do i remove the drops group/table here because i think it's not necessary

```
local physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

local W = display.contentWidth
local H = display.contentHeight

local createDrop=function()
local drop = display.newImage("drop.png")
drop.x=math.random(drop.width, W-drop.width); drop.y=-50
drop.type="drop"
physics.addBody(drop)

local function update()
    if(drop.y > H) then
        drop:removeSelf()
        drop = nil
            print("remove drop")
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", update)
    end

 end
 Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", update)

end
local dropTimer = timer.performWithDelay ( 1000, createDrop, 0)
```

Comment: Nope, I checked code again to be sure that if the drops are removed from memory but when i put them inside a display group, group's size is increasing. They are not removed! What do you say about it?

Comment: how do you insert them and remove them from your group? because i may not know where problem occurs unless i see your codes

Comment: I just insert them inside the createDrop function of your code and shouldn't it be removed when you remove drop in update?

Comment: i figure out that i did not put local on drop thats why it was conflict to the last object that spawn i will reedit my code

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it in an another way. This will ensure that every out of screen drops will get removed:

```
W = display.contentWidth  
H = display.contentHeight
local drops = display.newGroup()
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

local drop = {} 
local dropIndex = 0

local function createDrop()
    dropIndex = dropIndex + 1
    drop[dropIndex] = display.newImage("drop.png")
    drop[dropIndex].x=math.random(drop[dropIndex].width, W-drop[dropIndex].width)
    drop[dropIndex].y=-50
    drop[dropIndex].type="drop"
    drops:insert(drop[dropIndex])
    physics.addBody(drop[dropIndex])
    -- print(drops.numChildren) 
end
local dropTimer = timer.performWithDelay ( 1000, createDrop, 0)

local function update()
    for i=1,#drop do
        if(drop[i] ~=nil and drop[i].y >= H)then
            drop[i]:removeSelf()
            drop[i] = nil
        print("removed... drop["..i.."]")
        end
    end
end
timer.performWithDelay ( 10, update, 0)  -- you can also use enterFrame event instead
```

Keep Coding............. :)